# Having trouble with C++ Bitmaps

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp

I am attempting to produce code that yields an image with 1 pixel set to black, the problem is that the output is 8 horizontal pixels of black when I attempt to set a single pixel to black. I also attempted to set the pixel above to black, but it resulted in a horizontal line 8 pixels above the original.

So my question is, how can I change my code so I end up working with bits instead of bytes in my image? I just want to be able to set a single pixel to black instead of a byte of pixels.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

#define IMAGE_SIZE 256
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;

    char colorTable[8] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };

    char bits[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE];

    ofstream bmpOut("foo.bmp", ios::out + ios::binary);
    if (!bmpOut) {
        cout << "could not open file.";
        return -1;
    }
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(bmfh) + sizeof(bmih) + sizeof(colorTable);
    bmfh.bfSize = bmfh.bfOffBits + sizeof(bits);

    bmih.biSize = 40;
    bmih.biWidth = IMAGE_SIZE;
    bmih.biHeight = IMAGE_SIZE;
    bmih.biPlanes = 1;
    bmih.biBitCount = 1;
    bmih.biCompression = 0;
    bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 2835; 
    bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmih.biClrImportant = 0;

    // Here I am initializing a white background for the bitmap image

    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < IMAGE_SIZE; j++) {
            bits[i][j] = 255;
        }
    }

    // Here I attempt to set the most bottom left pixel to black and the pixel above it to black as well

    bits[0][0] = 0;

    bits[1][0] = 0;

    char* workPtr;
    workPtr = (char*)&bmfh;
    bmpOut.write(workPtr, 14);
    workPtr = (char*)&bmih;
    bmpOut.write(workPtr, 40);
    workPtr = &colorTable[0];
    bmpOut.write(workPtr, 8);
    workPtr = &bits[0][0];
    bmpOut.write(workPtr, IMAGE_SIZE*IMAGE_SIZE);
    bmpOut.close();

    system("mspaint foo.bmp");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a link to the bitmap image produced:
[Scaled up for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1kCZ.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [BITMAPINFOHEADER documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it looks like you are setting your bitmap to be read as monochrome by setting `bmih.biBitCount = 1`. This way every pixel is represented by one bit (black or white only), not byte. Thus, to set bottom-left pixel to black, you need to do `bits[0][0] = 127` (127 = 0x7F = 01111111b). To set one above it, I think you would need to do `bits[1][0] = 127`. In this case I also believe

```
char bits[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE/8];
...
for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < IMAGE_SIZE/8; j++) {
        bits[i][j] = 255;
    }
}
...
workPtr = &bits[0][0];
bmpOut.write(workPtr, IMAGE_SIZE*(IMAGE_SIZE/8));
```

would be enough.

If you intended to use different color palette, you should set different `biBitCount`, as described in the docs I linked to at the beginning, I guess you would want `bmih.biBitCount = 8` as a healthy default for your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You clarified that I am dealing with binary when setting the bits so I understand now how to specifically set any sort of permutation of the 8 horizontal pixels. I did try the method to set the pixel right above to black, but I couldn't get it to work for some reason.

Comment: @michael874, I understand that setting the lower-left pixel worked? How did you try to set the higher pixel, and what result did you get? I think it would be most comfortable for both of us to edit this info into the question.

Comment: @michael874 I have edited my answer, I got a little confused with the memory layout. Did you try it like that (`bits[1][0] = 127`)? It would be easier if you used a simple 1D array of `(IMAGE_SIZE/8) * (IMAGE_SIZE/8)` size insetead of the 2D one.

Comment: I did try bits[1][0] = 127 but it assigned the first pixel black in the 8th row, instead of the 2nd row (starting from the bottom).

Comment: @michael874 was your array declared like `char bits[IMAGE_SIZE/8][IMAGE_SIZE/8]` or `char bits[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE]` at this point?

Comment: Ah okay, so I was able to fix it by changing the array to `char bits[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE / 8];` and consequently changing the the bounds in one of the loops and `bmpOut.write(workPtr, (IMAGE_SIZE*(IMAGE_SIZE/8)));` Thank you very much! I will edit my original question with the solution.

Comment: @michael874 it would be better if you accepted this answer and removed the edit from the question for clarity for future readers, I fixed the sizing in the answer, as per your suggestion, which is most certainly correct